# Fedora's command-not-found doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, package-management, yum

I've recently installed Fedora 19. [Packagekit-command-not-found](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/PackageKitCommandNotFound) is installed. But it's own examples doesn't work. When I enter `gedti` the output is:

`bash: gedti: command not found...
Similar command is: 'gedit'`

And it works correctly but when I enter powertop, the output is:

`bash: powertop: command not found...`

With no suggestion about the package. Why? should I edit some configuration files or update some cache or ... ?